# Check one list against another list (VBA) using LBound and UBound . Or any way that works

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to check a PO list against an open PO list and clear the cell from 
 the PO List if not in the open PO List.  I tried multiple variations of code (below) and this one is giving me a Mismatch error. Usually, I do something like i = 0 to 5 but that's when I know the exact length of the list. Doing this without knowing the length has been a challenge. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
Sub POCheck()
Dim OpenPO As Worksheet
Set OpenPO = Worksheets("OpenPO")
Dim All As Worksheet
Set All = Worksheets("All")
Dim OpenPOList As Variant
OpenPOList = OpenPO.Range("A2:A" And LastRowPO).Value
Set AllPO = All.Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
Dim i As Long
LastRow = All.Range("AH" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
LastRowPO = OpenPO.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For Each cell In AllPO.Cells
For i = LBound(OpenPOList) To UBound(OpenPOList)
Found = False
If Not cell.Find(OpenPOList(i)) Is Nothing Then
Found = True
Exit For
End If
Next i
If Not Found Then cell.Value = ""
Next cell
```

Comment: Initialize LastRow and LastRowRO *before* using them, and try again. Also indent your code to make it more readable.

Comment: Would you mind showing me how to initialize before using them? Also, I will work on my indentation! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is very quick to use arrays and Application.Match to see if current value is in the array containing the values to match against. No looping cells and data is read in and written out in one go.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub POCheck()
    Dim openPO As Worksheet, all As Worksheet, lastRow As Long, lastRowPO As Long
    Set openPO = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("OpenPO")
    Set all = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("All")

    With all
        lastRow = .Range("AH" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    With openPO
        lastRowPO = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Dim openPOList(), allPOList(), i As Long
    openPOList = Application.Transpose(openPO.Range("A2:A" & lastRowPO))
    allPOList = Application.Transpose(all.Range("B2:B" & lastRow))

    For i = LBound(allPOList) To UBound(allPOList)
        If IsError(Application.Match(allPOList(i), openPOList, 0)) Then
            allPOList(i) = vbNullString
        End If
    Next
    openPO.Range("A2").Resize(UBound(allPOList), 1) = Application.Transpose(allPOList)
End Sub
```

Comment: on which line please? And can you verify the values of lastRowPO and lastRow ? If either are <2 then you will get this error.

Comment: Nevermind It works. I had some misspelled Variable names.  The only issue besides this was that it was clearing from the wrong list but that was an easy fix. Thanks!

Comment: Spoke to soon. Its clearing the cell in OpenPo but  I need it to clear the cell in all if it is not in PO.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered a best practice to add `Option Explicit` to the top of the code modules and declare a variables with the correct datatypes.

> ```
> Dim LastRow As Long, LastRowPO As Long
> ```

Use `&` not `And` when concatenating strings.

> ```
> OpenPOList = OpenPO.Range("A2:A" And LastRowPO).Value
> ```

`LastRowPO` is being used before its value is set.

```
LastRowPO = OpenPO.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
OpenPOList = OpenPO.Range("A2:A" & LastRowPO).Value
```

Use `Range.Find` to search a group of cells not a single cell.

> <s>If Not cell.Find(OpenPOList(i)) Is Nothing Then</s>

Using a `Scripting.Dictionary` to match unique values is vastly faster then using nested loops.  Watch: [Excel VBA Introduction Part 39 - Dictionaries](https://www.youtube.com//watch?v=dND4coLI_B8&index=43&list=PLNIs-AWhQzckr8Dgmgb3akx_gFMnpxTN5).

You should download [RubberDuck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) and use its code formatter often.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a vlookup to see if it exists and then clear the value if vlookup in adjacent cell isn't #N/A?

Or loop down the first list and do a countif in VBA to see if it resides within the other list, if it does, clear it?

So may ways to do it in VBA also...